# Why does the application of external mechanical pressure increase the performance of lithium-ion batteries?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, electrochemistry, redox

Many electric vehicle batteries - specifically lithium-ion ones considered for this query - can be subjected to external mechanical pressure because it increases battery performance.

What components of overall battery performance are affected and why?

Comment: Generally, high external pressure can suppress forming gases due side reactions or solvent evaporations. It may also improve cooling.

Comment: The  most likely effect is to reduce the thickness of the electrolyte layer, reducing internal resistance, by squeezing the electrodes closer. There is no outgassing during discharge of most cell chemistries.

Comment: [Here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0013468619305614) is a publication entitled "Analysis of the effect of applying external mechanical pressure on next generation silicon alloy lithium-ion cells." I believe your query can be addressed by the above comments and the information in the linked article (and citations within it).

Comment: @ewr3243 - I think your question is good; however, we do like to see a bit of effort from those who post here in re: getting towards an answer. Can you please edit-in your thoughts?